# How to encrypt txt files with AES256 via Windows 7z command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, encryption, 7-zip, aes

I have 7z on windows , and I want to encrypt 1 txt file with AES256 via 7z command line.

How can I do it please?

Answer (score 7):

To make the answer simple just use the switch `-p` which means Set Password with the default encryption which is `AES`.

The example below will encrypt the file or folder and prompt for a password:

- `7z a -p Zip_File_Name File_2_zip.txt`

The following example will auto add the password to the file for you.

- `7z a -pPassword Zip_File_Name.7z File_2_Zip.txt`

---

The other switches used above are:

```
7z a -p -mhe=on Zip_File_Name.7z File_2_Zip.txt

 -pPassword   ==  Auto add password without being prompted
 -mhe=on      ==  Means to encrypt the file names in archive too.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
7za u -mx -mhe -pPASSWORD ARCHIVE-FILE-NAME.7Z SOURCE-FILE-SPEC
```

Any time you use the .7z format, the file is AES-256 encrypted.

#### Arguments explained:

`-pPASSWORD`: setting the password `PASSWORD`.
`u`: update existing archive with new or modified files.
`-mx`: default compression level (5/6) -  `-mx1` (fastest) to `-mx9`.
`-mhe`: encryption of file headers (encrypted file names).

Comment: Can you please explain me what is the arguments `u` and `mx` and `mhe` ?  Thank you

Comment: One issue per question, please, as per house rules. https://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples offers details.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere? I can see that the -mem switch (EncryptionMethodID) is available for zip type. Documented here: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm - but the documentation does not say anything about the cipher used for other types. So how do you know?

Comment: Asking what your answer means is not against the "house rules"! If anything, giving a literal answer to the question without any explaination is against them.